# what is the real use case of dependency injection?

Tags: java, oop, dependency-injection

I understand **dependency injection** but what i really don't understand is, what is the use of dependency injection.

As it is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection) this helps in testing your code easily *(It's a very useful technique for testing, since it allows dependencies to be mocked or stubbed out.)* , but now a days there are lot of mocking frameworks like [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/), [powermockito](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/) which can do these jobs quite well than why dependency injection?

It would be great if somebody could explain with code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

The primary uses for DI as a technique are :

It leads to a code that is easier to test ( using Mocking ). This means that in order to use mocking frameworks ( Mockito etc ) , you should be using more of DI. If you dont use DI and write code that instantiates objects directly - then practically you cannot use Mockito to mock your dependencies.

Lets say you write code to play an Orchestra. Your main class depends upon so many other classes ( that other people wrote perhaps ).

Lets say you wrote this :

```
public class Orchestra {
  private Drums drum;
  private Violin violin;
  private Guitar guitar;

public Orchestra() {
    drum = new Drum();
    violin = new Violin();
    guitar = new Guitar();
}

public Music play(){
    // use above in some way to run your orchestra
    // start with violin 
    // add some guitar and then bring in the drums too
}
```

}

Now you want to ensure that your logic in `play` works accurately. When you run your class you see the music is not what you are expecting. ( maybe the drummming is starting right at the start ).  You want to test the logic of your code `play`. How would you do that here ? You have no control over your dependencies. You dont know if there was an issue with code of `Drum` or your own logic in `play()`.

You would want to **mock out** `Drum` here. But you cannot do that easily. Because your code does not use DI. Its instantiating the `Drum` directly inside.

Now lets use DI and see how it helps.

```
public class Orchestra {
    private Drums drum;
    private Violin violin;
    private Guitar guitar;

    public Orchestra(Drums d,Violin v, Guitar g ) {
        drum = d;
        violin = v;
        guitar = g;
    }

    public Music play(){
        // use above in some way to run your orchestra
    }

}
```

With this code , it becomes easy to mock out `Drum` in your test.

```
class TestOrchestra {

    public void testPlay(){
        Drum mockDrum = mock(Drum.class);
        Violin mockViolin = mock(Violin.class);
        Guitar mockGuitar = mock(Guitar.class);
        // add mock behaviour to above , here you control precisely what these dependencies will do inside your code

        Orchestra orch = new Orchestra(mockDrum, mockViolin,mockGuitar);
        // now play and test your logic

    }

}
```

The second advantage of using DI is that it helps vary implementations of bigger parts of your program without needing to go through your entire code.

Again - with reference to above , lets say you have been playing your orchestra using a particular type of guitar ( which is instantiated internally by your code).

Now you want to change to an brand new electric guitar.Without DI , you would have to open up your `Orchestra` class , check where you create the `Guitar`  and change that line of code. You would have to ensure that other parts of your code are not changed inadvertently and test entire `Orchestra` to make sure things work correctly.

With DI , you could avoid all this. You just inject the new `Guitar` object into your constructor. Thats it. Because you have tested the new `Guitar` object on its own ( and it fulfills the contract of the `interface Guitar` - you can be rest assured that your `Orchestra` code is not broken by injecting this new Guitar. Thats quite a better improving your orchestra.

Answer (score 8):

`Dependency injection` is not an alternative to `mocking frameworks`. It's a requirement. If you have hard dependencies, it's a lot harder to mock the dependencies and therefore test the code.

`DI` also allows you to have more loosely coupled code. Classes can use other classes simply by having them injected, instead of knowing how to construct (or obtain an instance of) a particular class.